# How to map Meta key to control key in vim?

Tags: vim

How do I map my Windows key (which is defined as the Meta_L key in Ubuntu) so that it also works as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key in Vim?  This is a more comfortable mapping for me in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are hard-coded into in the Vim source.  You can map your Windows key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> globally if you don't mind affecting all other programs too.  Some window managers will support doing this, or else you can use [xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html).  The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) has some info about mapping the Windows key to another <kbd>Esc</kbd> , which is similar.

Comment: It is not a WM feature, but an X server one. You can add `keycode {meta_L_keycode} = Escape` to `~/.Xmodmap` and, probably, also add `xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap` to `.xinitrc`, `.xsession` or to WM-specific startup file (example: `~/.fluxbox/startup` for fluxbox). This works, but may be overridden later by DE keyboard handlers, so if one is using KDE, Gnome or such he should first try to search for their own options.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remap all the sequences which use `<C->` to use `<M->` and put them in the separate .vimrc.

To receive the full list of current mappings use

```
:redir > ~/mappings | map | redir END 
:e ~/mappings
:g!/<C-/d
```

After that you will have all the mappings that use  key. Add same mappings to your .vimrc substituting

```
:help map
```

It is not a one minute job but it is how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to System settings > Keyboard > and Alt/Win key behavior > Control is mapped to Alt keys, Alt is mapped to Win keys. This is much better to use control with thumb.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using xmodmap and if you're using GNOME, you can go into the Control Center → Keyboard Preferences → Layout Options → Alt/Win behaviour → Control is mapped to the Win Key. (alternatively, run `gnome-keyboard-properties`)

Of course, this changes it for everything, not just vim.